# Lucene 4.6 get document vectors

Tags: vector, lucene

I would like to get the vectors of a number of documents using lucene 4.6 . I m quite new to Lucene and I cannot find a guide to help me. Can you please help me?
Note: I have already done index and searcher, i just need code how to take vectors of documents!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`getTermVector` method](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) of the `IndexReader` class.

```
indexReader.getTermVector(docID, field);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to ask you something more. I want to get the vector of the document as a double(type). How can I do that?